# swift FB loginSDK calls Google signin method instead of its own

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is driving me crazy. I Added FB Login to my swift 2.0, XCode Version 7.3. Working fine. But after I implemented the GoogleSingin Login, FB Login Stop Working.

What happens here is that FB SDK, when returning from authentication, it calls

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

And Google Sign In, has this method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
print("G+ in appdelegate")
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

The problem is, that if the Google Sign In method exist, FB SDK Login, Calls the GoogleSignIn method and it crash the app.

I've tried to direct call from G+ method to the FB Method, but this doesn't work either.

Is this a FB bug??  Should I report it to FB Developers??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both Google and Facebook Sign In to the first method and remove func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool from your application.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation) || FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```